# inserter iterator to insert in different container depending on predicate

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, iterator

Lets say I have a vector of numbers and I want to create two vectors to separate the numbers on odd and even ones. Easily with a simple for:

```
std::vector<int> odds;
std::vector<int> evens;
std::vector<int> numbers;
for (int number : numbers) {
    if isOdd(number)
        odds.push_back(number);
    else
        evens.push_back(number);
}
```

I would like to know if there any kind of inserter_iterator that can manage to do this so i can write something like

```
std::vector<int> odds;
std::vector<int> evens;
std::vector<int> numbers;

auto pred = [](int i) { return isOdd(i) ? True : False;};
auto identity = [](int i) {return i;};
std::transform(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers), some_inserter(odd, evens, pred), identity);
```

This is just out of curiosity, I'm trying to learn how algorithms and iterators work. A solution based on ranges is also valid.

Comment: There isn't anything like that in the C++ library, but you can write your own.

Comment: std::transform with an "identity" transform function is just std::copy.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I've changed my original code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::partition_copy` algorithm, as follows https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy

```
int main() {
    std::vector vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};//the vector to be partitioned
    std::vector<int> odds(vec.size());//will hold odds (to have the sam size as the original (the maximum case) )
    std::vector<int> evens(vec.size());//will hold evens

    auto [oddsEnd, evensEnd] =
            std::partition_copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), odds.begin(), evens.begin(), [](int i){return i%2!=0;});//will copy at the front (won't insert at the back)
    odds.erase(oddsEnd, odds.end());//to erase the undesired excess
    evens.erase(evensEnd, evens.end());//to erase the undesired excess

}
```

OR use `std::back_inserter`  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter (See the comments)

```
int main() {
    std::vector vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};//the vector to be partitioned
    std::vector<int> odds;//will hold odds
    std::vector<int> evens;//will hold evens

    std::partition_copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(odds), std::back_inserter(evens), [](int i){return i%2!=0;});//will insert

}
```

Comment: Sure, but why allocate all the storage in both vectors up front, when you can just use back_inserter and then not need to erase at the end?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I think this is more efficient isn't it?

Comment: No, because you're needlessly copying the content of vec twice at the beginning, and you use more memory than required at the end.

Comment: @JohnZwinck. So, pros and cons (OP can decide the appropriate approach)

Comment: This looks promising  but what would happen if I was not doing a copy but an actual transform (with something different than an identity predicate) ?

Comment: @jjcasmar U can use move iterators

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `for_each` which can be used almost like you described:

```
std::vector<int> odds;
std::vector<int> evens;
std::vector<int> numbers;

auto pred = [](int i) { return i % 2;};
auto identity = [](int i) {return i;};

std::for_each(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers), [&](int number) mutable {
    int iden = identity(number);
    if (pred(iden)) odds.push_back(iden);
    else evens.push_back(iden);
});

// Or with range-based loop:

for (auto &elem : numbers) {
    if (pred(iden)) odds.push_back(iden);
    else evens.push_back(iden);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not idiomatic since range-based for loops were introduced in 2011.  OP's original code is better.

Comment: @JohnZwinck you right, I added the alternative. Anyway I wonder if this answer is still necessary here, because asmmo answer is way better.